# Fastest way to count words of string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

How could I make this algorithm faster and shorten this code which counts word of given string?

```
int number_of_words(std::string &s) {
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    // skip spaces
    while (s[i] == ' ' && i < s.length())
      i++;
    if (i == s.length())
      break;
    // word found
    count++;
    // inside word
    while (s[i] != ' ' && i < s.length())
      i++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to copy the string on each call, pass it as const reference instead.

Comment: you can make it faster, but the **fastest** code is definitely not shorter because they'll be extremely complex with SIMD, multithreading, loop unrolling... And fastest is also relative because some code might be fast on a system but slower on another system

Comment: @Quimby thanks, do you know how to shorten the code?

Comment: What's wrong with the current length? The complexity makes sense. O(n) is the fastest you could do this.

Comment: std::regex rx("\\w+");
   int count = std::distance(std::sregex_iterator(text.begin(), text.end(), rx), std::sregex_iterator());

Comment: @RocketProcd Why it needs to be shortened? You could do away with only one `for` loop testing a single character and tracking `bool inside_word` and having `if`s changing it.

Comment: code is better if it has less lines of code

Comment: @RocketProcd `std::istringstream strm(s); std::string w; int count = 0; while(strm >> w) ++count;`  You should have piggybacked off of the solution to your [other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72069293/reverse-string-with-one-space/72077249#72077249)

Comment: @RocketProcd code *may* be better if it has fewer lines of code. Length and clarity  are related, but not equivalent. "Better" can also mean different things (faster, more maintainable, more debuggable, more readable, etc.)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks, I didn't understand true meaning of `istringstream` now I get it

Comment: `code is better if it has less lines of code` this isn't quite true. Look at libraries (for example the C++ STL) you'll see that they're very very long. Short, fast, maintainable, scalale and readable are almost never in the same sentence

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have one question, is this `if (i == s.length())break;` unnecessary? Today it came up to my mind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is quite alright, speed-wise. But if you want to make your code shorter, you may use [find_first_not_of()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) and [find_first_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) standard functions, like I did in following code that solves your task.

I made an assumption that all your words are separated by only spaces. If other separators are needed you may pass something like `" \r\n\t"` instead of `' '` in both lines of my code.

One small optimization that can be made in your code is when you notice that after first while-loop we're located on non-space character, so we can add `++i;` line for free before second loop. Similarly after second while-loop we're located on space character so we may add one more `++i;` line after second while loop. This will give a tiny bit of speed gain to avoid extra two checks inside while loop.

[Try it online](https://godbolt.org/z/bqcMKM53s)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int number_of_words(std::string const & s) {
    ptrdiff_t cnt = 0, pos = -1;
    while (true) {
        if ((pos = s.find_first_not_of(' ', pos + 1)) == s.npos) break;
        ++cnt;
        if ((pos = s.find_first_of(' ', pos + 1)) == s.npos) break;
    }
    return cnt;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << number_of_words("  abc  def ghi  ") << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
3
```